# Add a prefix/suffix to Woocommerce product name everywhere, including cart and email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and I have integrated some custom fields to allow the user to specify new values that I will later append to the product title.

I am using `update_post_meta`/`get_post_meta` to save the *new* information. This  part works fine.

Then I used the filter `woocommerce_product_title` to update the title. This filter is working fine when there is the use of `$product->get_title()` but will do nothing when using `$product->get_name()`which isn't an issue because in some places I don't want to append the new information.

I also used the filter `the_title` for the product page.

Basically my code looks like below where `return_custom()` will be the function than will build the new information based on the product ID.

```
function update_title($title, $id = null ) {

    $prod=get_post($id);

    if (empty($prod->ID) || strcmp($prod->post_type,'product')!=0 ) {
        return $title;
    }

    return $title.return_custom($id);
}

function update_product_title($title, $product) {

    $id = $product->get_id();

    return $title.return_custom($id);
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_title', 'update_product_title', 9999, 2);

add_filter( 'the_title', 'update_title', 10, 2 );
```

---

The issue arise when adding the product to the cart. The name used is the default one so my below code isn't enough to update the product name used in the cart. Same thing for the notification mails. I suppose this is logical since the email will use the information of the cart.

I am pretty sure that everything is happening inside [`add_to_cart()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1023-1128) but I am not able to find any filter/hook related to the product name.

How to make sure the name used in the cart is good? What filter/hook shoud I consider in addition to the ones I am already using in order to append my new information to the product title within the cart?

I want to make sure that the new title will be seen during all the shopping process. From the product page until the notification mail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will allow you to customize the product name in cart, checkout, orders and email notifications, just with one hooked function:

```
// Just used for testing
function return_custom( $id ) {
    return ' - (' . $id . ')';
}

// Customizing cart item name in cart, checkout, orders and email notifications
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_cart_item_name', 10, 1 );
function set_custom_cart_item_name( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Required since Woocommerce version 3.2 for cart items properties changes
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get the product name and the product ID
        $product_name = $cart_item['data']->get_name();
        $product_id   = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

        // Set the new product name
        $cart_item['data']->set_name( $product_name . return_custom($product_id) );
    }
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter.

`[woocommerce_cart]` shortcode uses `cart/cart.php` template, and the code displaying the title is this:

```
if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
} else {
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
}
```